# Android: Theme.Dialog layout - dynamically visible content being cut-off

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a 'dialog' Activity based on the built-in Android theme Theme.Dialog:

```
<style name="Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@android:style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/panel_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>        

    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>

    <item name="textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Inverse</item>

    <item name="textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorTertiary">@android:color/tertiary_text_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/secondary_text_light</item>
    <item name="textColorTertiaryInverse">@android:color/tertiary_text_light</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_dark_disable_only</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_light_disable_only</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryNoDisable">@android:color/primary_text_dark_nodisable</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondaryNoDisable">@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverseNoDisable">@android:color/primary_text_light_nodisable</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable">@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable</item>
    <item name="textColorHint">@android:color/hint_foreground_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorHintInverse">@android:color/hint_foreground_light</item>
    <item name="textColorSearchUrl">@android:color/search_url_text</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceLarge">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceMedium">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmall">@android:style/TextAppearance.Small</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargeInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceMediumInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Small.Inverse</item>
</style>
```

My layout for the Activity, I have a single EditText, a single Button and an invisible TextView I use to display messages to the user based on the validity of the EditText content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/dialog" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp">
    <TextView 
        style="@style/DialogMessage"
        android:id="@+id/error" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:visiblity="gone" />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/title" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ems="20"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/rename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="right" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

When the user is in portrait mode, and they enter some 'bad' text in the EditText, I make the TextView visible, and populate it with an appropriate error message.  This works fine, as everything shifts down, and the TextView is displayed great, even if the content spans multiple lines.  Now, in landscape, when I do the same, the TextView displays fine, but the bottom element (in this case the Button) is compressed to about half it's normal height.  Moving the elements around, if I put the EditText at the bottom, when the TextView is made visible, it too is compressed, and puttint the TextView at the bottom results in anything more than a single line of text being cut off.

I have tried forcing the issue after the TextView is populated by re-setting the sizes of the LinearLayout via:

```
LinearLayout dialog = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dialog);
dialog.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And I have tried re-drawing the LinearLayout after the TextView is populated by calling:

```
LinearLayout dialog = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dialog);
dialog.invalidate();
```

Neither worked.  Any ideas what is going on here?

Thanks,

Paul

Edit:

There is ample screen real-estate to show all three components fully... as a fully inflated TextView with the same content as I am dynamically inflating, and everything displayed fully.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Didn't figure out why this was happening, but figured out a work-around.  Switching the layout to a RelativeLayout solved the issue, and everything is now displayed properly using the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/dialog" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp">
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/inpt_title" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
    android:maxLength="100"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ems="20"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_rename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/inpt_title"
    android:layout_below="@id/inpt_title" />  
<TextView 
    style="@style/DialogMessage"
    android:id="@+id/error" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_rename"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/inpt_title"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/inpt_title" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. (from future!)